# Direct sum and similarity question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,C$ be $n\times n$ matrices and $B,D$ be $m\times m$ matrices.

Assume $A\oplus B$ is similar to $C\oplus D$.

Then, are $A&C$ similar and $B&D$ similar respectively?

If they are, how do i prove this?

Comment: Oh.. I just realized that this is false. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Suppose $n=m=1$ and $A=D=1$, $B=C=0$.